# LSP - Publish Diagnostics, all files receive all diagnostics

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, server

I implemented a Language Server using pygls in vscode. At the moment I am working on a tool to show warnings when code gets out of sync. I am managing the data for the diagnostics in a list on the server. It works fine, to the point when I open more than 1 file. The problem is that files also show the warnings/diagnostics of other files.
In pygls there is a function to publish the diagnostics

```
publish_diagnostics(self, doc_uri: str, diagnostics: List[Diagnostic])
```

In the Specification it is said, that doc_uri is the uri for which diagnostics are reported.

Lets assume I have 2 files opened, hi.py and bye.py.

I try to send diagnostics only to hi.py, so i call

```
publish_diagnostics(uri(hi.py), List[Diagnostics])
```

Where the list only contains the diagnostics for uri. But this doesn't work, bye.py also receives the diagnostics.

I would also be grateful for any workaround.

Comment: I found that it works if you open a file, but the moment you change it the problem occurs.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this have to do with the [tag:liskov-substitution-principle]?

Comment: I am sorry, it has nothing to do with it. I wanted to tag the short form of Language Server Protocol. I didn't notice the auto completion.

Comment: The strange thing is, that on "open" and on "save" only the right diagnostics are shown in the clients editor. On "change" it breaks. I double checked my code and watched what diagnostics are sent. No mistakes. Could it be the editor itself causing this?